# post-commit logic in salesforce apex Trigger life-cycle

Tags: salesforce

Can any one please explain post-commit logic in salesforce apex Trigger life-cycle?

How i can write post-commit logic?

What is System validation and Custom validation in salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

After Insert/Update/etc. trigger log is still pre-commit. The most effective way to do this would be to use a time based workflow based of a time field you set (though this will incur a significant delay), or to use the `@future` annotation to fire off an asynchronous method elsewhere to do this processing.

Answer (score 1):

This link from Salesforce docs is helpful in understanding the full process.
[Trigger and order of execution](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

Comment: I am using same link and try to understand last statement that is "Executes post-commit logic, such as sending email". Can you please explain what post-commit logic?

Answer (score 0):

After salesforce has committed changes to the database following post-commit logics can be -:

1) If in the trigger you have written a code to send email then after the complete trigger finishes and the updates are committed to database then salesforce sends the email. This action of sending email can be called a post-commit logic

Comment: That's the whole point. Is Salesforce handling that automatically? I don't want the mail to be sent, when Messaging.sendMail() is called, but just when the commit was successful.

Comment: Yes Salesforce handles that automatically. As per the invocation flow which Salesforce handles. If you receive any error in code, the complete transaction will fail. You can also use try catch to handle that scenario.